# Use appendTo to add a URL to an anchor href

Tags: jquery, click, appendto

I have been working on an issue which made me confused.
I'm new to java script. I have been trying to add a URL to an anchor href using `appendTo` and `click()` function in jquery.

This is my HTML code:

```
<a id="player"></a>

<a id="play-this-video" class="play-video" href="#" linkdata='href="http://site.com/file.flv"'></a>
```

and this is the jquery code I am using:

```
<script>
$("a#play-this-video").click(function() {
    var linkdata = $(this).attr('linkdata');
    $(linkdata).appendTo('a#player');                             
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't work! Am I right or something is wrong?!

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? you should read the [documentation for appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/). The function is to manipulate DOM elements, not attributes

Comment: as I said I'm new to javascript! I didn't really notice that I'm working with attributes and not DOM elements! thank you :)

Comment: did you take a look at my answer? did it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the href attribute of your `#player` link then use `.attr()`

```
$("#play-this-video").click(function() {
    var linkdata = $(this).attr('linkdata');
    $('#player').attr('href',linkdata);                             
});
```